# Why is sapply() taking my matrix and turning it into a list that I cannot factor?

Tags: r, sapply

I am using the sapply() function to create a new column of data. First, from my raw data of observations, every patient receives a number between 1-999, each number has a unique description, but they all fall into 1 out of 27 categories. My problem is that the 27 categories are not given in the raw data, so I have to look them up in a dictionary which has the categories that match the numbers 1-999.

Here is the raw data from a data set titled inova9:

```
ID AgeGroup  Race SexCode Org_DRGCode
9     9    75-84 White       F         435
10   10    75-84 White       F         441
11   11    45-54 White       F         301
40   40    14-17 White       F         775
70   70    75-84 White       F         853
120 120    55-64 White       M         395
```

Here is part of my dictionary:

```
MSDRG_num                                                MS.DRG_Descriptions_
1         1            Heart transplant or implant of heart assist system w MCC
2         2          Heart transplant or implant of heart assist system w/o MCC
3         3 ECMO or trach w MV 96+ hrs or PDX exc face, mouth & neck w maj O.R.
4         4       Trach w MV 96+ hrs or PDX exc face, mouth & neck w/o maj O.R.
5         5                     Liver transplant w MCC or intestinal transplant
6         6                                            Liver transplant w/o MCC
New_CI_Category
1      Organ Transplant
2      Organ Transplant
3 General/Other Surgery
4 General/Other Surgery
5      Organ Transplant
6      Organ Transplant
```

here are the 27 categories:

```
> levels(DRG$New_CI_Category)
[1] "Bariatric Surgery"                  "Behavioral"                        
[3] "Cardiovasc Medicine"                "CV Surg - Open Heart"              
[5] "General/Other Surgery"              "GYN Med/Surg"                      
[7] "Hem/Onc Medicine"                   "Interventional Cardiology - EP"    
[9] "Interventional Cardiology - PCI"    "Medicine"                          
[11] "Neonates"                           "Neurology"                         
[13] "Neurosurgery - Brain"               "Neurosurgery - Other"              
[15] "Normal Newborns"                    "OB Deliveries"                     
[17] "OB Other"                           "Organ Transplant"                  
[19] "Ortho Medicine"                     "Ortho Surg - Other"                
[21] "Ortho Surgery - Joints"             "Rehab"                             
[23] "Spine"                              "Thoracic Surgery"                  
[25] "Unspecified"                        "Urology Surgery"                   
[27] "Vascular Procedure - Surgery or IR"
```

So, I need to match up inova9$Org_DRGCode with MSDRG_num from my dictionary, then pull the corresponding category from DRG$New_CI_Catgory

I implemented the following:

```
ServiceLine1 = matrix(nrow=length(inova9$Org_DRGCode),ncol=1)
ServiceLine1 =    sapply(1:length(inova9$Org_DRGCode),function(i)as.character(DRG$New_CI_Category[DRG$MSDRG_num==inova9$Org_DRGCode[i]]))
Svc = as.factor(ServiceLine1)
inova9 = data.frame(inova9,Svc)
```

As, you can see, I created a column and now I can merge it with my original data, one-to-one.
I have four data sets like this, but it only works for two. The other two I receive this error:

```
> Svc = as.factor(ServiceLine2)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

And my data looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Neurology"

[[2]]
[1] "Medicine"

[[3]]
[1] "GYN Med/Surg"

[[4]]
[1] "Vascular Procedure - Surgery or IR"

[[5]]
[1] "Neurology"

[[6]]
[1] "Medicine"
```

How did sapply() turn my matrix into a list and how do i stop it from happening?

Comment: `c(sapply(...), recursive = TRUE)` or `unlist(sapply(...))` or `simplify = "array"` in `sapply` sometimes works

Answer (score 3):

You might save yourself a headache by converting your data.table, setting a key then simply joining.

```
library(data.table)
DT.DRG  <- as.data.table(DRG)
DT.dict <- as.data.table(your_dict)

## Set the key to what you want to join on 
setkey(DT.DRG,  ID)
setkey(DT.dict, MSDRG_num)

## Assign the column from DT.dict into DT.DRG, joining on the keys
DT.DRG[DT.dict, New_CI_Category := New_CI_Category]
```

---

#### Make sure the keys are of the same type

meaning that they are both `factor` or both `character`, etc

Comment: ...probably worth pointing out that this could likely be done in one line with simple indexing (assuming the dictionary doesn't have any gaps in the integer codes) and that unless performance is a concern, `merge` will also do the trick.

Comment: @joran indeed!  I do use these key-value type dictionaries often though

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Thanks for a whole new paradigm. I am not familiar with that package, but what I am doing is like MapReduce, so this helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `sapply` is a wrapper for `lapply` that tries to be smart about its return structure. When, for whatever reason, it can't figure it out, it will always fall back to a list because that is what `lapply` returns.

Now, I'm not entirely sure why that's happening *here*. Just reading your code, I would also expect `sapply` to return a vector and not a list. One possibility is that, for some value of `i`, the expression `as.character(DRG$New_CI_Category[DRG$MSDRG_num==inova9$Org_DRGCode[i]])` has length greater than one. You can check this with `any(sapply(ServiceLine1, length) > 1)`.

In any case, the function `unlist` will compress a list down to a vector, so you can do `as.factor(unlist(ServiceLine1))`.

Comment: I did not think about the length being greater than one and now I understand a little more about why sapply() does what it does. Another way to unlist to a matrix is do.call(rbind,ServiceLine1), which I just found in another forum. Thanks for your help

Comment: @VectorTraverse that code will generate a column matrix, which is not equivalent to a vector. R makes it easy to be very, very sloppy with data types. Unfortunately, because R is not always so self-consistent, and because package developers are given lots of leeway in how they choose to (or not to) handle variable types, this sloppiness can lead to lots of maddening errors and unexpected behavior. Chapters 2-6 of the _Introduction to R_ manual outline the different data structures. That sounds like a lot, but there are only a few "basic" data types and it's an easy manual to skim.